# Get Content From Site After Logging In Using PHP

Tags: php, curl, authentication

I am trying to create a script that will login to my chosen website which is **IPT**.

I have managed to login and get the data but not quite sure on how i could get the data i want and then save it to a db which will eventually output it to Wordpress.

Here is what i have so far:

```
<?php       

login("http://iptorrents.com/torrents/","username=userhere&password=passhere");
echo grab_page("http://iptorrents.com/torrents/"); 


function login($url,$data){
    $fp = fopen("cookie.txt", "w");
    fclose($fp);
    $login = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($login, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, "cookie.txt");
    curl_setopt($login, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, "cookie.txt");
    curl_setopt($login, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 40000);
    curl_setopt($login, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
    curl_setopt($login, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($login, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']);
    curl_setopt($login, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, TRUE);
    curl_setopt($login, CURLOPT_POST, TRUE);
    curl_setopt($login, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
    ob_start();
    return curl_exec ($login);
    ob_end_clean();
    curl_close ($login);
    unset($login);    
}                  

function grab_page($site){
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 40);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, "cookie.txt");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $site);
    ob_start();
    return curl_exec ($ch);
    ob_end_clean();
    curl_close ($ch);
}

function get_data($url){
    $ch = curl_init();
    $timeout = 5;
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, $timeout);
    $data = curl_exec($ch);     
    curl_close($ch);
    return $data;
}

$returned_content = get_data('http://iptorrents.com/torrents');
echo($returned_content);

function post_data($site,$data){
    $datapost = curl_init();
    $headers = array("Expect:");
    curl_setopt($datapost, CURLOPT_URL, $site);
    curl_setopt($datapost, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 40000);
    curl_setopt($datapost, CURLOPT_HEADER, TRUE);
    curl_setopt($datapost, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
    curl_setopt($datapost, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']);
    curl_setopt($datapost, CURLOPT_POST, TRUE);
    curl_setopt($datapost, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
    curl_setopt($datapost, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, "cookie.txt");
    ob_start();
    return curl_exec ($datapost);
    ob_end_clean();
    curl_close ($datapost);
    unset($datapost);    
}

?>
```

after this all i get the login page i am requesting but then it also brings up the login forms below all.

I think i am probably just not staying logged in so maybe i should use sessions and store the login?

I am wanting to grab each of the id's from the site **every 10 minutes** say and then scrape certain content from those and in the end output it to my own format.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you need to hold onto your session cookie for repeat requests after logging in. Rather than doing this in Curl, I'd strongly recommend using a mature HTTP client library.

I'd recommend http://guzzlephp.org.

Working with cookies: http://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/latest/plugins/cookie-plugin.html

Comment: thanks for the fast response, i will have a look into these and see what i can work out.
I have a few people i know that have accomplished what i am trying to do but they won't let on how they have done it as they don't want me to be able to get content and post it to a website as easy as them.

Rather annoying as i just like learning stuff like this, it's a small project of mine.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do something much simplier (you will log with cookies and will need some [options](https://www.php.net/curl_setopt): CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR and CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE):

```
function curl_request($action, $postfields = array(), $ref = "") {
    $absolute_path = realpath('./');
    $timeout = 20;
    $useragent = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.1; fr; rv:1.9.2) Gecko/20100115 Firefox/3.6';
    $referer = (empty($ref))  ? $action : $ref;
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $action);
    if (!empty($postfields)) {
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postfields);
    }
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, $timeout);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $useragent);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, $referer);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    
     // these two lines will keep the cookies to get you logged
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $absolute_path."/cookie.txt");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $absolute_path."/cookie.txt");

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
    $status = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
    $contents = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    
    $data = array($contents, $status);
    return $data;
}

$credentials = array(
    "username" => "userhere", 
    "password" => "passhere"
);

curl_request("http://iptorrents.com/torrents/", $credentials); // we save the cookie

$data = curl_request('http://iptorrents.com/torrents');
$returned_content = $data[0];
echo($returned_content);
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion "Louis XIV" but that suggestion doesn't login when i try it. My credentials don't log me in.

I will edit the code a bit and try get it working but i can't seem to login using this method.

Comment: Maybe the site is giving you a cookie to assure you came on the login page so you can try to begin by making a dummy request to http://iptorrents.com/torrents/

Comment: make also sure the file cookie.txt has been created and is not empty (I may also have made a typo).

Comment: Will have a look and see. Fairly new to php. Just want a script to login, get the I'd's of certain genres and then scrape certain parts. Output the scraped data to a specific format I create in html then I can do the rest manually, thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a little bit old but for the sake of those who may face this problem in the future, I had the same issue in using curl and after searching and trying many codes, the codes below served my purpose:

```
<?php
//Login page
$loginURL = 'www.example.com/login.php';
//target page we want to fetch content;
$target = 'www.example.com/target.php';

//Initiate first curl request
$ch = curl_init();
//Create a coockie to save session state
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, "cookie.txt");
//Set login url
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $loginURL);
//login request is a post request
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, TRUE);
//set login page field names and their value
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,
array(
'login_username' => 'userName',
'login_password' =>  'password',
'realm' => 'local',
'action' => 'login'
));

//Execute login request
ob_start();
curl_exec ($ch);
ob_end_clean();
curl_close ($ch);
unset($ch);

//Initiate second curl request  
$ch = curl_init();

//Return transfer and avoid printing the output 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);

//get session state
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE,"cookie.txt");
//request our target page
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $targetURL);
//The line below is optional for php 5.1 and higher 
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER, true);

//Execute curl request and get the content of the target page
$content = curl_exec ($ch);
//close the curl request
curl_close ($ch);

//display the content in the our page
echo $content;
?>
```

Not to forget this code only fetches the html page and for example images are not shown in the output.